# Connecting without Microsoft Health App

Tags: android-tv, microsoft-band

I've been tinkering with the microsoft band for a while and i'm trying to connect it to a raspberry pi 3 running android TV(couldn't find any Android phone images), now i've got most normal apps running on the rasp , the microsoft health app crashes when i start it.

Funny thing is though, the costum app i've made to track all the sensors stil gets data from the band when paired, but the band itself just:
says "pairing succes! return to the microsoft health app to continue" So there has to be a way to bypass the app right?

So i'm trying to find a way to get the band linked to this device without the Health App. Or a way to get that app running on my Android image.

I got a logcat of the crash, but i'm not sure if that would be really usefull. Since i can't edit the microsoft health app itself ...right?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the band.
Pair the band to an android phone using health app.
Unpair band from Android phone.
Turn off Bluetooth on band.
Turn on Bluetooth on rpi.
Do a regular (not using health app) pairing the band and the rpi.